# CiviCRM Smart Group Based on Contact's Drupal Role

Tags: drupal, smartgroups

I need all users of a particular Drupal role to be added to a CiviCRM Smart Group. (All Drupal users are currently also CiviCRM contacts.)

The site uses CiviCRM 4.4.21 and Drupal 7.56

Comment: You could look in to Drupal Rules (maybe with Civicrm Entity) to see if you can add to Civi Group.

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM Group-Role Sync doesn't work with smart groups - but you can make a static group to sync to and make it a child group of the smart group.

Comment: i thought Group-Role sync worked Civi > Drupal. Question seems to be asking for the reverse.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Group-Role sync is bidirectional: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/blob/7.x-master/modules/civicrm_group_roles/civicrm_group_roles.module#L58